# Parar um worker e continuar o parallel pool em matlab

Tags: matlab, paralelismo

Tenho um código com um `parfor` simples em matlab que chama os workers.

```
parfor valor= 1:fim

        [output, out] = Computacao(dado1, dado2, int32(valor));
end
```

dentro da função que é chamada tenho um if para uma condição na qual se encontrado um erro ele deveria parar, porém queria que parasse apenas um worker para o valor = 3 por exemplo, e todos os outros fossem computados normalmente.

eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
if or(((aaa+4/3*sss)./ddd) < 0, mu < 0)

    problemaaa = 1;
    fprintf('PROBLEM FOUND');
    error('deuruim');

end
```

Porém quando ele encontra o erro ele não para apenas o cálculo do índice com erro, para todas as computações em andamento. Existe uma forma de eu matar apenas o worker daquele índice que encontrou o erro e continuar normalmente?

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro pra mim, mas acho que você apenas quer pular para a próxima iteração caso algo específico aconteça, para isso você pode usar o `continue`, ele vai continuar tentando as próximas condições, um exemplo básico seria esse:

```
for n = 1:50
    if mod(n,7)
        continue
    end
    disp(['Divisible by 7: ' num2str(n)])
end
```

Resultado:

```
Divisible by 7: 7
Divisible by 7: 14
Divisible by 7: 21
Divisible by 7: 28
Divisible by 7: 35
Divisible by 7: 42
Divisible by 7: 49
```

No exemplo o algoritmo pula para a próxima iteração caso o número não seja divisível por `7`, você pode fazer o mesmo quando o seu worker tiver o valor = 3, no lugar do `error` coloque um `continue`

```
if or(((aaa+4/3*sss)./ddd) < 0, mu < 0)

    problemaaa = 1;
    fprintf('PROBLEM FOUND');
    continue

end
```

Espero que eu tenha entendido o seu problema ...